# Save docker container settings like port mapping and volumes

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new on Docker. I have my Image in my docker repo:
[image: my docker image]

and I create a container from the images in this way:
[image: my docker container]

How can I save my docker run parameters for future use without to write them at any creation of containers from my image? Is Dockerfile the solution? (I never used Dockerfile yet).

PS: there is a way to "squash" the intermediate images (those without name) of my falongi/pyload image?

Thanks
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a docker-compose.yaml file to define the startup of your container(s). You can describe your parameters in it and start your container (with the parameters) with one single command: `docker-compose up -d`

Your .yaml file will containt something like (did not test it!!)

```
version: '2'
services:
  pyload-service:
    image: falongi/pyload:latest
    container_name: pyload
    volumes:
      - /mnt/rf/xxx:/mnt/mybooklive
    ports:
     - "8100:8000"
```

You can start it with: `docker-compose up -d`.
With docker-compose you have the possibility to deploy multiple containers at the same time. You can also define which Dockerfile to use instead of building the image by yourself. 
Than you'll need something like this in your dockerfile:

```
build: ./path/to/dockerfile
```

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) could be useful.

Edit: 
When you perform `docker images -a` you will see the parent image and its child layers. For more information I'll point to this [document](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/)

Comment: Interesting... I'll install and test docker-compose. About image delete, If I try to delete those images, I get the error that notify me about image dependency of others parent images...

Comment: I'm sorry I see you are performing `docker images -a`. This ULR will explain what you are seeing (parent image with its layers). This is normal: http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/ (If you just want to see the parent image you have to perform `docker images`). I thought you were seeing what are called the 'bad' ones in the article.

Comment: Thank you. One last question: I suppose I can't launch a container from an image with dockerfile. With dockerfile I can generate only one image, not a container from an image, right?

Comment: If I create an image with the specification of network mapping, volumes, ecc... Then my container will have this settings? Or I need to specify again the parameters with docker run command? I ask it because I could define one dockerfile that start with my local image and specify the parameters in it. Right?

Comment: A dockerfile is a description of how your image must look like. It does not contain the information of how your container will run. So e.g. you aren't able to map a port inside a dockerfile. You can only expose it. So you have to set this parameters in your docker run command (like you did) OR in a docker-compose.yaml file (like in the example of the anwser). A docker-compose file is a description of how to run your container(s)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your PS (lorenzvth7 covered docker-compose.yml for your title question):

The images you are seeing are each of the layers that are built up using the union file system. To reduce the number of layers, you need to minimize the number of commands in your Dockerfile. This means using a single `RUN` command that is joined with `&&` and long lines split with a `\` at the end of each line.

The layers are very important for caching in Docker. You can have a single base layer that is used by multiple images. That base layer will only get downloaded once, and with the design of the RO layers of the union file system, it only exists once on the file system even when you are running multiple containers that reference that image.